# Issues with losing all documents when going to deployment url

Tags: google-app-maker

I wanted to share with other users in my company a Google App Maker app I have been developing.  When I develop the app and use Preview, my data is all kept.

But I know I can't use the preview url for other users to access the application.  So I Published the app and got a deployment url I could give to other users.  The problem I am having is that all documents created are gone for myself (and I assume the other users) each time I open a new window with the deployment url.

How can this be fixed.  I am thinking there is something silly I am missing or doing.

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same issue, but I think this is because when using Google Drive Tables, they are local to the app instance.  So your development app tables are not the same as the published app tables.  Also, if you Published your app twice, it would be 2 different sets of tables (I think).  There is a way to import/export  data, so you may want to export the data from your development tables and import to your published tables.

[Google App Maker Import and export data](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/import-export)